# SceneKit RunAction command take too much memory space

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I noticed that when application using SceneKit runs the memory usage increase
steadily. After some search I pin pointed it to **aNode.runAction**.

Every time **runAction** is called it gets a bit of memory space and never release it.

Because **runAction** is used often in the application it is obvious that it is going to crash it.

Is there something to do to avoid that problem?

I am using this kind of functions to move some nodes.

I tried moving one node but nothing changed it takes less memory that is all.

```
  func moveMyNodes(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, z: CGFloat, speed: CGFloat) {
    for k in 0..myNodes.count {
      let action = SCNAction.moveBy(x:x, y:y, z:z, duration: speed)
      myNodes[k].runAction(action)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without running instruments on it, but dependencies would include the types of nodes you are using (amount of detail), if nodes are being removed and added (cleanup nodes - set geometry to nil), then check retain cycles.

Comment: No, this happens even without removing and adding nodes. To test I just removed **.runAction** lines and memory issue is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
In loop some of the nodes did not have geometry because they should not be seen.
When .runAction executed for a node without geometry it takes a bit of memory and they add up.

I've just get rid of nodes without geometry.